# Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006) React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I just literally don't understand how "data" is underlined with the 7006 error, but in the test environment literally on the front page (https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Quickstart) of React Hooks, it works.

Am I missing a dependency or need to have another file or import something?

I am having this problem on in another area as well.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data);
  }; // your form submit function which will invoke after successful validation

  console.log(watch("example")); // you can watch individual input by pass the name of the input

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>Example</label>
      <input name="example" defaultValue="test" ref={register} />
      <label>ExampleRequired</label>
      <input
        name="exampleRequired"
        ref={register({ required: true, maxLength: 10 })}
      />
      {errors.exampleRequired && <p>This field is required</p>}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);

export default App;
```

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Although the code works, TS warns you that it can't infer the type of `data` from your code, and it falls back to implicit `any` because of that. You need to manually set the type of `data`, or to set a type somewhere that TS can infer the type of `data` from.

In this case, you need to pass the definition of your form data when calling `useForm()` (see [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#TypeScript)). You'll also need to wrap the `onSubmit` with `handleSubmit`. Working example - [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-typescript-forked-jhe1p?file=/src/index.tsx).

```
type FormData = {
  example: string;
  exampleRequired: string;
};


function App() {    
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm<FormData>();
  const onSubmit = handleSubmit(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

And use `onSubmit`:

```
<form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
```

Comment: Read the docs link I've added. You also need to wrap `onSubmit` with `handleSubmit` for the type inference to work in this case.

Comment: I'm aware but you didn't state that in your answer until you edited. The way they have it in their code, TypeScript can't infer the type of `data` because it's not wrapped at the definition of `onSubmit`, it's wrapped farther down when it's passed to the `onSubmit` prop in their JSX.

Comment: Yea. I've figured that you'll see the edit (you read the original answer after all), so I didn't bother stating it. I've missed the `onSubmit` when going over the example in the docs the first time. It doesn't change the fact that declaring the the basic shape of the form (and using the library correctly) will solve everything using inference.

Comment: I don't think it would be immediately obvious to someone unfamiliar with TypeScript why wrapping the function in one place causes an error, but wrapping it in another place doesn't, even when the two appear to be functionally equivalent. That was why I had suggested adding that line in your answer. I did upvote after you edited though. Sorry for coming across as a pedant.

Answer (score 2):

That's a TypeScript error, not a runtime error. It's saying that you've defined a function (`onSubmit`) whose parameter (`data`) does not specify a type.

Combining the TypeScript examples from [here](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started) and [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api#handleSubmit), you should do this:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";
// -------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

type Inputs = {
  example: string,
  exampleRequired: string,
};

function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, errors } = useForm<Inputs>();
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = data => {
  // -----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log(data);
  };

  ...
```